# Deploy issue in ASP.NET Core (403-Forbidden Access Error)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

While uploading my asp.net core website to plesk hosting, 403-Forbidden access error pops out. How this can be resolved?

In ASP.Net MVC5 we use `<customErrors mode="Off">` to check for errors. But how to enable error page in ASP.Net core?

Here is the code for my appsettings.json:

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=.\MSSQLSERVER2016;Initial Catalog=GraniteHouses;User ID=coretest;Password=0!6Qcdr8;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;Packet Size=4096; Persist Security Info=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
    },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I expect my website to be working.

Comment: I would start by using SQL Server Management Studio and very you can connect to database with the username and password in your connection string.  Check the login window to see if Windows Credentials is being used or a SQL Credential is being used.  I suspect you will need to use a Widow Credential but not sure.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How to get this done on live hosting? My website is not working on live hosting. On local, it is working fine.

Comment: I think runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests = true.  Not sure.  found a lot of hits saying this solved 403 on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that Plesk installed on Windows, as ASP.NET Core is not supported on [Linux Plesk server](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000442805-ASP-NET-Core-support-in-Plesk)

Deployment package should contain `web.conig` package, which looks more less like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You can set `stdoutLogEnabled` to true, than logs will be written to this `.\logs\` folder(you might need to create this folder/give write permissions).

That will help you to get error

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am not being able to find the web.config package anywhere in my hosting. Help me please

Comment: In visual studio right mouse button click on your web project, there will be publish command, click it select Publish to local system(or something like that). That's will be the package you should deploy to your web server and that package will contain Web.config